# Restrict Access to API in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, permissions

One Azure App service hosts a asp.net core API, another different Azure app service hosts a Web app. The web app can be accessed by end users that don't need to sign in (public). The web app calls the API. How can the API access can be restricted so that only the web app hosted in Azure can make calls to it, but end users cannot directly call the API end points, but the end users can still access the website (webapp)?

Answer (score 0):

You asked a simple question that risks taking you down a rabbit hole.  There are many ways to secure an API.  The good ones require some thought.

On way is to involve a token server.  The application and the token server share secrets.  When application that wants to call an API, it is somehow redirected to the token server, and is granted a token.  The session is redirected back at the API.  The API checks with the token server that the token is authentic.  If it is, the API serves the data, otherwise it fails.

This is an incredibly simplistic description of what really happens.  Read everything in https://oauth.net/2/ for more details. Azure has mechanisms in the portal that can be used.  https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html talks about how Identity Server could be used.  There are other services of varying complexity and expense to do this.  There are experts with varying rates that can help.  I hope these couple links can get you started on your security journey.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Skip Saillors, I will explore these.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to tweak the access restrictions of the app service to control the inbound access.

It allows to IP restrict/ Service tag based restrictions for an app service to accept traffic only from these entities.